# How to build and return multiple objects from MVC Controller

Tags: c#, list, csv, model-view-controller

**Scenario:** I currently have a data repo layer building an IList from the annual data read from the .CSV that it passes to the Controller, and the Controller to the View layer (see code below).

The .CSV file is very large. Each row contains 200+ columns of data for an individual:

- Annual data (e.g. Maths, PE and English exam results each year for over a decade in the format of ##.## percent). Will grow over time
- Non-annual data (e.g. name, gender, year of birth, postcode)
  Not every person has results for every year or every subject.

I could do 2 reads of the CSV to build a separate List, but prefer to do only one read for performance.

I need both in the control layer so I can do some calculations using the annual and non-annual data (e.g. count of above average math scores for each postcode). Once I have both in the Controller together I'm confident I can progress a long way.

How to get the other data from the same .CSV and return it to the same controller in a separate List variable, e.g. an IList (annualData) and a List for the rest (otherData).

Maybe there's a better way with 2 separate methods, I just may not know enough to be asking the right question(s).

I'm sure there is a way to return both an IList and a List between layers together, but after a few attempts I've rolled back all my code as they were starting to unravel my tenuous understanding of the code below.

The approach may have been right, but my execution had a flaw and gave VS suggestions/errors I didn't understand well enough to fix.

Don't be fooled by the code below, I've gotten to this point with a lot of help. I am very new to OO, C# and MVC. It's a lot to get my head around after a long break from coding (pre-OO days), so Please be explicit with the layers used in your suggested solution.

Thanks in advance.

**Current code:**

Data Repo Layer

```
public class myDataRepoLayer
{
    public IList<AnnualDataModel> GetAnnualDetail(string theirIDcode) 
    {
        IList<AnnualDataModel> annualData = new List<AnnualDataModel>();
        
        // get CSV row data by ID code
        myDataModel thatData = new myDataModel();

        // Read the CSV file (for the row with the unique code provided by the parameter)
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:/myFiles/Data of the people.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            thatData = csv.GetRecords<myDataModel>().Where(x => x.IDcode == theirIDcode).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        // map data to model FY2009
        AnnualDataModel FY2009 = new AnnualDataModel()
        {
            Year                  = 2009
            , Eng     = thatData.Eng2009
            , PE       = thatData.PE2009
            , Maths = thatData.Maths2009
        };
        annualData.Add(FY2009);

        // map another year's worth of data to model
        AnnualDataModel FY2010 = new AnnualDataModel()
        {
            Year                  = 2010
            , Eng     = thatData.Eng2010
            , PE       = thatData.PE2010
            , Maths = thatData.Maths2010
        };
        annualData.Add(FY2010);
        return annualData;       // How do I also return a List here?
    }
}
```

Data Layer

```
namespace mySite.Models
{
    public class AnnualDataModel   // This is used to build the IList of the annual data
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public Decimal? Eng { get; set; }
        public Decimal? PE { get; set; }
        public Decimal? Maths { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
namespace mySite.Controllers
{
    public class myLessonController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult HistoricPerformance()
        {
            myDataRepoLayer repo = new myDataRepoLayer();
            // How do I get back the iList and another List with this call? How do I then use those two vars?
            IList<AnnualDataModel> aData = repo.GetAnnualDetail("DDD");     //Later replace DDD with UI search field  
            // From the annual data get the fist and latest year data is reported, the difference (total years data) all for calcs later on, and if there were results every year
            // firstYearIndex (int), lastYearIndex  (int), YsofData (int), dataEveryYear (bool)
            (int index0, int indexN, int ycount, bool dataAllYears) years = (0, 0, 0, false);
            years = YearsOfData(aData);

            IList<AnnualDataViewModel> vm = new List<AnnualDataViewModel>();
            foreach (var y in aData)
            {
                AnnualDataViewModel v = new AnnualDataViewModel();

                v.Year = y.Year;
                v.Eng = y.Eng;
                v.PE = y.PE;
                v.Maths = y.Maths;
                // Convert all the annual Decimal data to the format to display them in e.g. #.##%
                v.TextEng = y.Eng.HasValue ? (y.Eng.Value / 100).ToString("P") : "";
                v.TextPE = y.PE.HasValue ? (y.PE.Value / 100).ToString("P") : "";
                v.TextMaths = y.Maths.HasValue ? (y.Maths.Value / 100).ToString("P") : ""; ;
                vm.Add(v);
            }
            return View(vm);
        }
    }
}
```

View Model

```
namespace mySite.ViewModels
{
    public class AnnualDataViewModel
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public decimal? Eng { get; set; }
        public decimal? PE { get; set; }
        public decimal? Maths { get; set; }
        public string TextEng { get; set; }
        public string TextPE  { get; set; }
        public string TextMaths { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

HTML (View layer)

```
@*@model mySite.ViewModels.AnnualDataViewModel*@
@model List<mySite.ViewModels.AnnualDataViewModel>
<table style="width:100%" id="Their Annual Results">
    @foreach (mySite.ViewModels.AnnualDataViewModel item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td align="right">@item.Year                   </td>
            <td align="right">@item.TextEng                </td>
            <td align="right">@item.TextPE                 </td>
            <td align="right">@item.TextMaths              </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what myDataModel looks like and the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to return a data structure from a method you could create a new object with two properties eg:

```
    public IList<AnnualDataModel> AnnualDataModel { get; set; }
    public List<OtherDataModel> OtherDataModel { get; set; }
```

Or since c#7 we could use Tuples - lightweight data structures that contain multiple fields to represent  -see documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7)

I am going to use Tuples. With that in mind the structure will be as following:

```
public class AnnualDataModel 
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public Decimal? Eng { get; set; }
    public Decimal? PE { get; set; }
    public Decimal? Maths { get; set; }
    public string TextEng { get; set; }
    public string TextPE { get; set; }
    public string TextMaths { get; set; }
}
```

From above you can see I am moved the Text property within the `data` class.

```
public class OtherDataModel
{
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

The above is an example of the other data you have mentioned. I have no access to the actual .csv file - will leave the correction to your discretion.

The `GetAnnualDetail()` will look like this:

```
    public (IList<AnnualDataModel> annualData, List<OtherDataModel> otherData) GetAnnualDetail(string theirIDcode)
    {
        IList<AnnualDataModel> annualData = new List<AnnualDataModel>();
        List<OtherDataModel> otherData = new List<OtherDataModel>();

        //get data from csv and fill both List and IList
        //......
        //......
        // Do Convert all the annual Decimal data to the format to display them in e.g. #.##% here 
        // Make the class responsible for getting the data responsible for its conversion


        return (annualData, otherData);       // How do I also return a List here?
    }
```

Now since the data all the data is retrieved and converted by the responsible classes, your viewmodel can be simplified:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IList<AnnualDataModel> AnnualDataModel { get; set; }
    public List<OtherDataModel> OtherDataModel { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller then you can make the following call in order to the details:

```
    MyDataRepoLayer data = new MyDataRepoLayer();
    ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();

    vm.AnnualDataModel = data.GetAnnualDetail("3").annualData;
    vm.OtherDataModel = data.GetAnnualDetail("3").otherData;
```

***EDIT***

Single call to MyDataRepoLayer

```
(vm.AnnualDataModel, vm.OtherDataModel) = data.GetAnnualDetail("3");
```

HTML Model to be changed to:

```
@model mySite.ViewModels.ViewModel

......

@foreach (AnnualDataModel annualData in Model.AnnualDataModel)
{
    <tr>
         ....
    </tr>
}

@foreach (OtherDataModel otherData in Model.OtherDataModel)
{
    <tr>
         ....
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, That's a huge help. My only question is, are those last 2 lines `GetAnnualDetail("3")` doing two calls and thus two reads of the CSV, and is there a way to retrieve both the Annual data and Other data in a single read?

Comment: Also, I assume in my HTML I'll now need to `@model mySite.ViewModels.ViewModel` and modify my `@item` to pull reference relevant items in either AnnualDataModel or OtherDataModel. I'll try that tonight.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Very much appreciated. That's unblocked me and I'll get a few weeks coding further down the track now.